# Retrieving data from two collections in MongoDB with PHP having _id as a value already

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I'm trying to use aggregate to return token and kyc_status in an API call.

I have below data in `tokens` collection

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5fca628feb1f03d82c76e85f"
},
"user_id": "5fca62d0eb1f03d82c76e860",
"token": "token_here",
"valid_till": "2021-01-03",
"created": "2020-12-04 20:27:05",
"modified": "2020-12-04 20:27:05"
}
```

then I have below data in `users` collection

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5fca62d0eb1f03d82c76e860"
},
"seller_type_id": "",
"status": {
    "$numberInt": "1"
},
"kyc_status": "pending",
"username": "user_name",
"password": "password_here",
"email": "email_here",
"primary_contact": "primary",
"secondary_contact": "secondary"
}
```

Now i have id `5fca62d0eb1f03d82c76e860` in $user_id PHP variable

I'm using the below code to achieve to show `kyc_status` and `token`

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(   [
        [ '$lookup' =>  [
                                'from' => 'users',
                                'localField' => '_id', 
                                'foreignField' => 'user_id',
                                'as' => 'user_role'
                                ]
        ],
        [ '$unwind' => '$user_info' ],
        [
            '$project' =>   [ 'kyc_staus' => '$user_info.kyc_status' ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

I do not get any out put when I print the $result variable it shows me a whole lot of data but does not show what I want, I searched and tried most of StackOverflow answers to the same but did not get any.

Can anyone let me know where i am goring wrong / what should i do to get the desired output?

Comment: What code do you have to access and print the expected results.

Comment: Also, why are you using aggregation?  Aggregation is for grouping/summarizing data.

Comment: Ok even if my code would not be as being portrayed, but i think the ask is clear. can you help me to attain it?

Comment: you are saving the data in `user_role` and then trying to project from `user_info` - typo perhaps?

Comment: I am storing data in users, then I'm storing token when a user logs in but what I want to do is when user logs in I also want to pass Th kyc_statys from users collection. In mysql I'll do something like select users.kyc_status, token.tokens FROM users, tokens WHERE users.id = tokens.user_id;